# VBA code stops without error, ment to delete modules and forms from target workbook

Tags: excel, vba, forms, module

So I have multi workbook system. On start the start workbook should make a copy of a target workbook, delete all modules and forms, protect it with password, save it and close it. All this works fine except deleting the modules and forms. When I disable the DeleteAllMacros sub the code works well: it makes a copy, protects the workbook, saves and closes it and continues to next procedure.

When I enable the DeleteAllMacros sub the code stops (without any errors) right before the sub and doesn't delete the modules or forms. The procedure does not continue and nothing happens. When I run manually the DeleteAllMacros it works just fine and all modules and froms are deleted.

I can't figure out what is the problem since the code actually works fine but when I try to call it, it just stops. Below the important parts of the code:

```
Public Sub Copy_file(C)

'[removed some code that is not necessary for the problem]

Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False                                ' disables automated link update
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable  ' disables macros running on start

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fn, Password:=pw, UpdateLinks:=0)


Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI          ' enables macros running on start
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True                                 ' enables automated link update

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

    Sheets(i).Unprotect Password:="XXXX"

Next i

Call BreakExternalLinks(wb, pw)                                 ' Remove links

Call kill_macros(wb)                                            '


Application.DisplayAlerts = False                                    ' Skips the are you sure you want to save
Workbooks(new_name).SaveAs Password:="XXXX", Filename:=fn
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Workbooks(new_name).Close
End Sub

----------------------------------------

Public Sub kill_macros(wb)

Dim otmp As Object

With wb.VBProject
For Each otmp In wb.VBProject.VBComponents
    If otmp.Type = 100 Then
        otmp.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, otmp.CodeModule.CountOfLines
        otmp.CodeModule.CodePane.Window.Close

    Else
        wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove otmp

    End If

Next otmp

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anywhere in the code you excluded: `OnError resume next` ?

Comment: Try using `F8` to step through one line at a time until you find out where the issue lies.

Comment: I would not recommend to tinker with the VBE - why not save the file as Macro-Free workbook (xlsx)?

Comment: What is the value of `Sheets.Count`? References should be fully qualified.

Comment: @FunThomas the workbook will end up corrupted (or that's what excel at least thinks) if I try to save it as a .xlsx

Comment: @Luuklag No there is no Onerror statement included. I tried to include it but the result is the same

Comment: @ashleedawg Seems like it actually runs the kill_macros but to wrong workbook.. I don't understand why because it is quite well defined to which workbook I want the sub to do its magic

Comment: @KasperNurmi, you shouldn't include it, as it hides any errors that might occur.

Comment: If your workbook gets corrupted when saving it as xlsx, I would assume that it's already corrupt before the save.

Comment: @FunThomas the file is fine when I save it as a .xls. If I comment the Call kill_macros(wb) the code works just fine (of course it doesn't delete forms and modules but otherwise it works)